# If someone was color blind in one eye could that be explained by being a fraternal chimeric twin?

Tags: science-based, biology, humans, colors

Say you had a tribe whose members each had one color blind eye, could this be explained by the absorption of fraternal twins in the womb? (Say chimerism was prevalent because it helped fight off disease/cancer)

Comment: This isn't about worldbuilding so much as pure biology. Please take our [tour] and read-up in the [help] about how we work. If you do decide to ask on the biology site, please ensure to take their tour and read their help center for guidance as to what's on-topic before you post. Welcome to worldbuilding.

Comment: Taking it a bit farther:  You could have a colorblind tetrachromat.

Comment: [biology.stackexchange.com](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) is that way ->

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, It's not the only reason, depending on your sex. However, biology SE definitely seems like the best place for this, since it's about a real world biology question rather than a fictional world building one.

Comment: There is no rule that says that if a question is a better fit for another stack it is automatically unsuitable for WB.SE:  [being on-topic on another site does not make a question off-topic for Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6161/a-proposal-to-finalize-the-are-real-world-questions-on-topic-debate).  However, @bryandunn , you should provide the worldbuilding context for your question.

Comment: Looks like the recent edit with the mention of "tribe" here is a tactic to make it look like this isn't a straight up biology question. Voting to leave closed until you offer some actual worldbuilding context.

Comment: @elemtilas You could literally add: "Say there's a fantasy world where..." to any question on SE. This question should remain closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  **Your person can be an XX/XY chimera.**

[Natural human chimeras: A review](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1769721220302895)

> Only 28 of the 50 individuals with a 46,XX/46,XY karyotype were either
> true hermaphrodites or had ambiguous genitalia.

You can have your character be a hermaphrodite if that advances your story, or not.  If your character is a male / female chimera then one eye is male and one is female.  The male eye is colorblind.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness

> The most common cause of color blindness is an inherited problem in
> the development of one or more of the three sets of the eyes' cone
> cells, which sense color.[3] Among humans, males are more likely to be
> color blind than females, because the genes responsible for the most
> common forms of color blindness are on the X chromosome.[3] Females
> have two X chromosomes, so a defect in one is typically compensated
> for by the other.

Of course your person could also be an XY/XY chimera, with no possibility of hermaphrodism.  Usually colorblind people are XY and so XX/XX would be trickier.

Comment: Or an XX/XX chimera.  Color-blind females are rarer, since it's recessive, but it's possible.